# Is there any open code to get information about COLLADA or OBJ files?

Tags: implementation

I need a source code that takes as input a COLLADA file and/or an OBJ file, and gives as output basic information about the file, such as file size, model dimension, volume and if possible texture issues.

Comment: obj is simple enough to write a parser for, collada also has free libs to parse it.

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off topic here, but you may be interested in [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For OBJ Files**

Free tools like [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/), [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), and [GLC_Player](http://www.glc-player.net/) are able to load OBJ files and give you basic information about their content.

Apparently, GLC_Player can also load COLLADA.

In code you can use the following standard tools:

1. [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) - Library for loading many common formats including OBJ
2. [TinyObjLoader](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) - .h/.cc only, no external dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I have written a standalone java program (ObjectVolume) which reads an object file (.obj) and calculates the surface area, centroid and volume of any closed triangular mesh. The program also displays the file name, number of faces, the number of 3D coordinates and program run times. The program is in the public domain and is located at:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/objectvolume/?source=navbar

Included is a detail description of the process and the code.  The source code is included so you can add whatever you like.